# Translation verification

Tags: grammar-choice, sentence-translation, translation-check, case, english-to-latin-translation

I’m wondering whether my translation is correct. 
I wrote:

> tempus fugit; sed muscae fugiunt etiam.

I meant for this to mean:

> Time flies, but flies fly too.

I really don't have any knowledge of latin, just a general liking for languages. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pun does not work in Latin.

Comment: Fly (the insect) = musca. Fly (to run away) = fugio. Fly (to fly with wings) = volo.

Comment: @fdb owhm well thanks anyway :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation is quite good! I don't think I would use both *sed* and *etiam* here; *etiam* on its own seems sufficient. And it typically comes second in the clause. So I would say:

> *Tempus fugit; muscae etiam fugiunt*

However…

The pun, unfortunately, doesn't work in Latin. The verb *fugere* means to flee or run away, the noun *musca* means the insect, and the verb *volāre* means to move through the air. None of the three words are related or look particularly similar. (The translation above assumes that the flies are running away, e.g. from a flyswatter; if you want to say that flies move through the air, you would need *volant*.)