# Which verb do insects fly with?

Tags: classical-latin, verbs, word-choice, passage-request, animals

Having read [a question (and answer) about flies flying](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6614/79), I started to wonder whether flies would really fly with the verb *volare*.
I had always somehow imagined that *volare* referred to more elegant and graceful flight, such as that of birds or mythological characters, rather than flapping small wings at very high frequency and making a buzzing sound like an insect.
I may well have misunderstood the nuance, and the point of this question is to set that straight.

So, **which Latin verb(s) do insects fly with in classical Latin?**
Is *volare* applicable to them as well, or is some other choice more idiomatic?
A quote or two from classical authors would be great.
I assume the Romans would mention a fly flying somewhere in the extant literature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe *volare* is used indeed with various insects, such as bees, flies, and cicadas. From the HP corpus:

---

> Publius Ovidius Naso, Ars Amatoria 1.95, 1.96:
>
> *Granifero solitum cum vehit ore cibum,
>
> Aut ut **apes** saltusque suos et olentia nactae
>
> Pascua per flores et thyma summa **volant**,
>
> Sic ruit ad celebres cultissima femina ludos:*

---

> L. Iunius Moderatus Columella, De Re Rustica 6.17.9.5:
>
> *sed quotiensque mel  9.1
> aliusue sucus remediis adhibetur, circumlinendus erit oculus
>
> pice liquida cum oleo, ne a muscis infestetur. nam et ad dulcedinem et ad odorem mellis aliorumque medicamentorum non eae [i.e. **muscae**] solae, sed et **apes aduolant**.*

---

> Gaius Plinius Secundus, Naturalis Historia 11.96.2, 11.96.3:
>
> *Insectorum autem quaedam binas gerunt pinnas, ut muscae, quaedam quaternas, ut apes. membranis et **cicadae volant**.*

---

> Apuleius Madaurensis, Metamorphoses 10.15.8:
>
> *... nec utique cellulam suam tam immanes **inuolare muscas**, ut olim Harpyiae fuere, quae diripiebant Phineias dapes.*

---

I've looked at all other entries meaning "to fly" in my dictionary, and it seems (composite) forms of *volare* are the only ones used with insects; that is, the other ones all seemed to be used poetically c.q. metaphorically for flying, such as *curro, findo, labor* and a swarm of others.

Answer (score 4):

There's "avolo" (fly off); "provolo" (fly out); "subvolo" (fly up). in Betty Halifax's book of (elementary) translations, remember; "vespa ter volavit circum puellam."
Prosaic but effective.